# WebSecurity SimpleMembershipProvider not working together?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

Getting a bit disappointed with all the weird exception I keep running into while working with WebSecurity. Also the poor integration with OAuth doesn't make it look prettier. Considering to drop the concept and write the whole user management manually...

Anyway, I am using WebSecurity to administer users and passwords. Now I try to implement the part where accounts can be deleted. Weirdly enough this method is not on the static class WebSecurity. Apparently I need to delete accounts via the SimpleMembershipProvider.

```
var provider = new SimpleMembershipProvider();
provider.DeleteAccount(username);
```

The deleteAccount method throws an invalidoperation exception with the following message:

```
You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call 
any other method of the "WebSecurity" class. This call should be placed in an 
_AppStart.cshtml file in the root of your site.
```

Well that's weird since I already have this in my _ViewStart (otherwise I wouldn't have been able to create the accounts in the first place).

```
        if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
        {
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(
                "DefaultConnection",
                "Users",
                "UserId",
                "UserName",
                true);
        }
```

What am I doing wrong this time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
Membership.DeleteUser(username);
```

Comment: i guess you earned your badges for a reason :). That works! Could you shed some light on this tho? When to use SimpleMembershipProvider? When I define a custom database as user account storage?

Comment: In ASP.NET MVC 4 the default membership provider is the `SimpleMembershipProvider`. So you're already using it when you use the `Membership` class. You don't need to pollute your code with membership provider specific calls such as instantiating a new SimpleMembershipProvider and then calling methods on it. Your code doesn't work because you never initialized the new instance of the SimpleMembershipProvider that you created.

Comment: @Darin: Your comment is much more valuable and instructive than the answer above. Thanks.